# Convert File Hierarchy to MutableTreeNode in Jtree

Tags: java, swing, file, jtree

I have hierarchy of File structure in Java.. How do I convert that to a DefaultMutableTreeNode heirarchy.
I tried fetching each file individually, checked each if directory or not, did a recursive loop and formed a File structure. Now, to convert it to DefaultMutableTreeNode, do we have any utilities or its just again we need to do top-down approach to check and convert them again node-by-node.?

Do we have any utilities as such already?

Need suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in utilities for create a JTree model from a filesystem snippet.  There is a [file chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) if that is what you are after.  Otherwise I would say that your approach seems reasonable to me.  I would probably convert the files to a DefaultMutableTreeNode in one pass.  Something like:

```
public class FileNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
  private File file;

  public FileWrapper(File file) {
    super(this);
    this.file = file;
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
      for(File file : listFiles) {
        add(new FileNode(file));
      }
    }
  }

  private String toString() {
    return file.getName();
  }

  private File getFile() {
    return file;
  }

}
```